# Efficient iteration over a combinatorial subgraph of a bipartite graph using Boost Graph Library

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, graph, combinatorics

*Basic problem:*

I've got a matrix of probabilities, where the Rows are "Blue" and the Columns are "Red". The matrix is typically very sparse, but we are unable to guarantee its sparseness. I'm doing a probabilistic analysis of this matrix consisting of probabilistic ANDs and ORs; Basically I need to do every combination of Blues, working with every "N choose K" combination of Reds. I have decided to try to do this using a Graph, specifically a bipartite graph using Boost Graph. Edges are only inserted for values greater than 0.

*An example:*

Matrix:

```
        Red
Blue   0.01    0.04    0.07
       0.02    0.05    0.08
       0.03    0.06    0.09
```

Graph: Bipartite with 3 Red and 3 Blue vertices

```
R1 --> B1 (edge weight 0.01)
R2 --> B1 (edge weight 0.04)
R3 --> B1 (edge weight 0.07)
...
```

*Continuing the Explanation*

I keep track of Red vertices and Blue vertices by storing the vertex IDs in vectors. I generate the combinations by marking the red vertices either Black or White based on the N choose K (using the "vector of bools permutation" method). I then use recursion to run through every combination of Blue edges to get every valid combination of Bx->Ry edges.

There is exactly one edge for every Blue (or, more precisely, for every Blue that connects at all to the "White" Red vertices). This makes it far easier to run the analysis on the Blues; by doing so I use recursion and simply use a for loop over every Edge the Blue has to generate all valid sets of valid combinations of B->R.

*For the above Example:*

For 3 choose 2 on Red:

First iteration: `White: R1, R2    Black: R3`

Generate all valid combinations of Bs going to R1 or R2 where R1 and R2 are represented at least once in each combination in the set of combinations.

Second iteration: `White: R1, R3   Black: R2`

Generate all valid combinations of Bs going to R1 or R3 where R1 and R3 are represented at least once in each combination in the set of combinations.

Third iteration: `White: R2, R3    Black: R1`

Generate all valid combinations of Bs going to R2 or R3 where R2 and R3 are represented at least once in each combination in the set of combinations.

Sets for first iteration: `{{B1R1, B2R1, B3R2}, {B1R1, B2R2, B3R2}, ...}`

(There must be at least one edge from each column so `{B1R1, B2R1, B3R1}` is not a valid combination; Further only one edge from a given Blue vertex can be included in the combination so `{B1R1B1R2...}` is also not valid.)

*The problem:*

Right now I'm filtering out "Black" Red vertices (not running the probability calculations on the edges) by checking the target of the edge during recursion on Blue. While this works very well, it is very inefficient and often results in unacceptable run times. For very sparse matrices, this results in O(N!) time being wasted on lots of nodes and edges. For small, or very sparse, matrices this is not an issue. But for large, "not sparse enough" matrices the run time explodes. "Good" run times are typically on the order of 100ms, often closer to 10ms; "Bad" can take hours (one run took more than eight hours and didn't finish). Effectively I'm doing a DFS on Blues and dropping any combinations that include invalid ("Black" Red) vertices.

*The Question:*

Hopefully I've been clear enough on this problem.

I have only been able to find two possible solutions to making this more efficient, but I'm hoping a reader has another idea:

1) Generate combinatorial subgraphs and iterate over those using the current method. Example: For "First Iteration" above, copy the graph and remove all edges that go to R3. Then, by definition, all edges in the recursion are "useful" edges.

2) Figure out a way to generate the same combinations by iterating over the Reds (as by definition, all edges going into a "White" Red vertex is valid).

My understanding of the way Filtered Graphs work is that they would basically do the same thing that I'm doing now (filtering "on the fly" rather than prefiltering), so it wouldn't actually improve my time.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

Option 1 turned out better than I thought; I was able to get a 100 x 100 matrix to work in less than two seconds. Still looking to see if anyone has ideas for option 2 though.

Comment: I think some people may be inclined to look at your actual code. It sounds like a job of adapting a custom graph container (perhaps based on (a few) boost intrusive views of the actual edges?)

Comment: I actually did think about that. Unfortunately the code is *way* too big to post here. Even just the relevant snippets ...